# Mobile Menu Icon Issues

Tags: css

Working on this mobile page:

http://mockup.comule.com/ (may contain pop-ups!)

Currently only working on the mobile aspect. When in the mobile view, the yellow menu 'Hamburger' icon is shown. I copied its CSS from elsewhere. Before it was used, the word 'Menu' was in its place. I didn't remove this word - the icon replaced/covered it.

The html markup still shows the word 'Menu' as being present:

Menu

The newly-added CSS:

```
.handle {
    background-color: #990000;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;text-align:right;
    padding: .75rem .5rem;
    display:block;
}

.handle:after {
    content: "";
    border-color: yellow;
    border-style: solid none double;
    border-width: 4px 0 12px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 2rem;
}
```

What I want is the menu icon to appear on the right-hand-side of the bar and the word 'Menu' to re-appear on the left.

What needs to be changed in order for this to happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"Menu" written on left and menu icon on right, for this try following:

```
.handle:after {
    content: "";
    border-color: yellow;
    border-style: solid none double;
    border-width: 4px 0 12px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 2rem;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -4px;
}


.handle {
    background-color: #990000;
    text-align: left;
    padding: .75rem .5rem;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 90%/1.3em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

And for "Menu" on right and icon on left, try this:

```
.handle:after {
    content: "";
    border-color: yellow;
    border-style: solid none double;
    border-width: 4px 0 12px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 2rem;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -4px;
}


.handle {
    background-color: #990000;
    text-align: right;
    padding: .75rem .5rem;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 90%/1.3em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Also just to inform, I am not sure about the  "margin-top: -4px" in ".handle:after", it would be either -4px or -18px, try it out and let me know which works.

Comment: Thank you very much. The -4px is the one used. I was thinking originally I had to use z-index because 'Menu' was hidden!!!! Thanks again...